# How can I render {%%} of Markdown in Jekyll?

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll, liquid

I want to embed the following html code in markdown.

```
<! doctype html>
<title> Hello from Flask </ title>

{% if name%}
  <h1> Hello <br> {{name}}! </ h1>
{% else%}
  <h1> Hello, World! </ h1>
{% endif%}
```

The following error occurs when rendering this markdown by jekyll.

```
jekyll 3.8.0 | Error: Liquid syntax error (line 111): Tag '{%%}' was not properly terminated with regexp: / \% \} /
```

I do not know how to solve it, so I leave a message.

How can I express my html code on a blog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`{% raw %}` block](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/raw/):

```html
{% raw %}
<!doctype html>
<title> Hello from Flask </title>

{% if name%}
  <h1> Hello <br> {{name}}! </h1>
{% else%}
  <h1> Hello, World! </h1>
{% endif%}
{% endraw %}
```

Use whitespace control or place tags on the same line as appropriate.